# php open 2 tcp socket

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

When I open 2 different sockets in php, I first get different resource id, but after open next socket, get equal resource id.
Below is the result of the connection to three different sockets

```
# ./test.php
```

127.0.0.1:26379/132458106d92e8f7b
127.0.0.1:26379 - Resource id #8
127.0.0.1:6380/320458106d92e906e
127.0.0.1:6380 - Resource id #9
127.0.0.1:6381/102858106d92e9106
127.0.0.1:6381 - Resource id #10
Resource id #10Array
(
    [timed_out] =>
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] =>
    [stream_type] => tcp_socket/ssl
    [mode] => r+
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] =>
)

Resource id #10Array
(
    [timed_out] =>
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] =>
    [stream_type] => tcp_socket/ssl
    [mode] => r+
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] =>
)

Resource id #10Array
(
    [timed_out] =>
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] =>
    [stream_type] => tcp_socket/ssl
    [mode] => r+
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] =>
)

I'm use below code:

```
class RedisClient    
function __construct ($arr = array ())
    {
        if (count($arr) === 0) return FALSE;

        self::$host = $arr[0];
        self::$port = $arr[1];
        self::$persistent = '/' . uniqid(rand(100,10000));

        self::$fp =
            stream_socket_client('tcp://'.self::$host . ':' .
                                 self::$port .
                                 self::$persistent, $errno, $errstr, self::$connect_timeout, self::$flags);

        echo self::$host,':',self::$port,self::$persistent,PHP_EOL;

        if (!self::$fp) {
            echo "$errstr ($errno)" . PHP_EOL;

            return FALSE;
        }

        echo self::$host,':',self::$port,' - ';
        print_r(self::$fp);
        echo PHP_EOL;

        if (!stream_set_timeout(self::$fp, self::$timeout)) return FALSE;

    }

function getMeta ()
    {
        print_r (self::$fp);
        print_r (stream_get_meta_data(self::$fp));
        return;
    }

$c=new RedisClient(array('127.0.0.1',26379));

$m=new RedisClient(array('127.0.0.1',6380));

$s=new RedisClient(array('127.0.0.1',6381));

$c->getMeta();
echo PHP_EOL;
$m->getMeta();
echo PHP_EOL;
$s->getMeta();
echo PHP_EOL;

exit;
```

Anybody know, why after all sockets connected, all Resource id, are indentical?
And how make it different ?

Comment: I think using static variable in non-static context would yield a warning or notice. You shouldn't mix contexts this way but also declare your variables in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used self::$fp (static variable), you need use $this in class to get different variable by object.

**"self::$var = 1;"** - create one variable to class (without object)

**"$this->var = 1;"** - create attribute in object

For example you can write:

```
class Test {
   protected $a = 1;
   protected static $b = 1;
   public function incA()
   {
       $this->a++;
   }
   public static function incB()
   {
       self::$b++;
   }
   public function getA()
   {
       return $this->a;
   }
   public static function getB()
   {
       return self::$b;
   }
}
$test = new Test();
$test->incA();
$test->incA();
var_dump($test->getA());
var_dump(Test::getB()); // or $test::getB();

Test::incB();
$test2 = new Test();
var_dump($test2->getA());
var_dump($test2::getB());
var_dump($test::getB());
var_dump(Test::getB());
```

[Read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)